# Change Layout in Angular Material Expansion Panel

Tags: angular, layout, angular-material, angular-material2

How can I change the layout inside of the expansion panel to have a layout of row?
As far as I can tell no matter what type of `<div fxLayout="row" ...` etc I try it will always have a column layout inside the expansion panel.

Example Code:

```
<mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <mat-panel-title>
        Skills
    </mat-panel-title>
</mat-expansion-panel-header>

    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
            <div>
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
    </div>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

Will return

```
Test
Test
Test
```

Comment: you should check what rule is overriding the style of the outer div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have included the flex-layout module - if you aren't sure about that, try replacing the fxLayout properties with a class that sets { display: flex; } or just add it inline on that div with style="display: flex;". (flex-direction:row is the default)